# Was the driver intentionally screwing over the two goons at the start?

Tags: character, analysis, drive

So in the first scene, the guy went for the good old 'get lost in the crowd' kind of trick by driving into the stadium full of people, leaving the car behind, altering his appearance quickly, and then just slithering through the crowd until far away from the approaching police.

**My question is, what did he expect the guys he was transporting to do to avoid detection in this case?**

The driver himself wore a special coat that can just be turned inside out to change color and disappear, but the goons he drove that night wore *completely inconspicuous all-black costumes and were also carrying bags full of money* (presumably). They sure didn't look like sports fans and would just be face-planted into the ground as soon as the cops saw them.

- How was he expecting them to get out of that?
- Was he intentionally screwing them over? I don't imagine he would get a lot of demand for his services if he did that.
- Was this whole situation way worse than expected, and did he just decide to save himself, all else be damned?

Comment: He's paid to drive the car. He's not paid to save the goons from their own bad planning.

Comment: @magarnicle Don't think he told them to plan on being taken literally into the stadium w/ tons of people and cops all over haha

Comment: No, you're right that it seems weird. I doubt he would do screw them over intentionally, though. Business would dry up for him very quickly if he got a reputation for doing that.

Comment: Haven't watched the movie in a while, is it implied they didn't escape?

Comment: @Luciano I initially thought that the guy that walks up to him in the diner was one of those robbers (he says his brother was killed and he went to jail which I assumed was after their little stunt at the stadium) but the locations don't match it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Driving to the game was the plan**

Although not clear from the movie, the screenplay tells us that the robbers were aware of where they were going.

> Driver glances at the armed robbers and nods. It's time. They
> climb out of the car, merging in with the crowd. Driver watches
> them disappear, then slips on a Clippers cap, climbs out of the
> Impala himself and heads towards another car.

Comment: I don't think we're given that interpretation in the movie. We only see him get out, don the cap & swiftly move away. There are no words exchanged, he doesn't even glance back at them, not even in the mirror.

Comment: As I said we don't see it in the movie but the screenplay does seem difinitive.

Comment: It seems The Driver planned: we see his TV with the game on at the beginning, he follows the game on the radio the whole time, he has the blue cap. But did the robbers know that was the plan?

Comment: Whats funny is that they could easily show it but chose not to. By having them exit first or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first rule we see established in the movie, in the opening telephone call.

To paraphrase… "You have me for five minutes. After that, you're on your own."

This scene then demonstrates the rule to the audience and the fact that he will stick to it no matter who he abandons in the process. We don't yet know enough about the driver's character to extrapolate a lot further at this point.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation here. The five minutes relates to the time he will wait for them before leaving, not the time taken to escape IMO

Comment: I don't read it that way, but tbh there are many things in that movie that seem designed to make you misread them, are badly explained or not explained at all. I've watched that first 10 minutes more than anyone really needs to now, so I think I might just drop it in the bin so I don't have to watch it again… ever ;))